Knave and Knight
You arrive on the island of Knights (who always tell the truth) and Knaves (who always lie) and encounter two inhabitants, A and B.
(a) A states “If I am a knave, then B is a knight!”. What can you conclude?
(b) B replies “I am a knight or 2 + 3 = 5”. What can you conclude? (You may use what you learned from part a here)
Explain your solution fully.
So I know we have to start by breaking it down into if A is a knight or a Knave. If A was a Knight he would be telling the truth and so we know that he is not a Knave so because of that B would have to be a Knave or a Knight.
But if A was a Knave then the first part would technically be correct but we know that because Knaves lie the second so we know that B would have to be a Knave.
I'm having a little trouble with how to conclude this part.
And so for the second part I broke it down that either B is a Knight or a Knave.
To start if B was a Knight because he is using the word or we know that either the first part is true or the second part it. So he is telling the truth about being a Knight and we know that 2+3 does not equal 5.
This is where I have gotten so far, I'm not sure how to continue or if I am correct so far. Any help would be amazing!

Nothing to do with probability.  Please edit to include your efforts.

Welcome to MathSE! What have you tried?

Even less to do with boolean algebra.  Are you picking these tags at random?

Voting to reopen as the asker added their efforts to solve the problem

Hint: You can rule out B being a Knave because what he says can't be false, since it's a tautology (a logical truth).

Here is some feedback on your reasoning:

So I know we have to start by breaking it down into if A is a knight or a Knave. If A was a Knight he would be telling the truth and so we know that he is not a Knave so because of that B would have to be a Knave or a Knight.

Basically yes. If A is a knight, then that doesn't force anything about B: B can still be a knight or knave.

But if A was a Knave then the first part would technically be correct but we know that because Knaves lie the second so we know that B would have to be a Knave.

Yes, very good. If A is a knave, then A's statement is false, so under the assumption that A is a knave, it cannot be true that B is a knight. In sum: if A were a knave, then B would have to be a knave as well.

To start if B was a Knight because he is using the word or we know that either the first part is true or the second part it. So he is telling the truth about being a Knight and we know that 2+3 does not equal 5.

OK, so far so good. But note that $2+3$ does equal $5$. So, we have a problem if we assume that B is a Knight.
But what if B is a Knave?  Well, then B's statement should be false. But B's statement is true, since $2+3=5$ is true, and B is not a Knight. So, we also have a problem when B is a Knave?
Yeah, no wonder you got stuck!  OK, here is what I am pretty sure is going on. The use of the English 'or' is ambiguous: sometimes we use it as an exclusive or, and sometimes as an inclusive. For example, when a mathematician claims that all whole numbers are even or odd, they mean that as an exclusive or: Whole numbers are even or they are odd, but never both (being even excludes it from being odd, and vice versa). When the waiter in a restaurant asks you whether you want 'soup or salad' with your main dish, they probably mean you can have one, but not both, so again exclusive.  However, if you say you want to be rich or happy, you are of course perfectly fine with being both. So that's an inclusive or: it is also true when both parts are true.
Now, what you did in your reasoning was to interpret B's usage of 'or' as an exclusive or:  you said that if B is a Knight, then his statement is true, and since the first part ('I am a knight') is true, that would exclude $2+3=5$ from being true as well ... and now you got all kinds of contradictions!
However, having done enough of these puzzles, I can tell you that typically they mean an inclusive or ... unless they state very explicitly that an exclusive or is meant.
So, try thinking about B's statement again, but treat B's use of 'or' as an inclusive or, and see what happens now.


(a) A states “If I am a knave, then B is a knight!”. What can you
conclude?

A is ether a Knave or a Knight.
Suppose A is a Knave. Then the statement is false, which means (antecedent is true, and consequent is false). That is, what is true is that assuming A is a Knave, B also must be a Knave.
Following this scenario consistently we assume A be a Knave when B replies. So if A is indeed a Knave, then B would also have to be a Knave. But let's see if what B says can be false:

(b) B replies “I am a knight or 2 + 3 = 5”. What can you conclude?
(You may use what you learned from part a here)

Assuming B is a Knave, we expect the statement they utter to be false. But it can't be false, because it is a tautology.
Hence, it's not the case that A is a Knave and B is a Knave. Hence the statement in (a) seems true, but that would imply that A is a Knight. Let's analyse that scenario.
Assuming A is a Knight “If I am a knave, then B is a knight!” is true, which is logically equivalent to “I am either a Knight, or B is a Knight!”. So for that to be true, given the assumption that A is a Knight, B could be anything, since one of the disjuncts is already satisfied. But since the proposition uttered by B cannot be false, B uttering it speaks the truth, which is consistent with B being a Knight and the truth of what A says.
Hence, we can conclude that both A and B are Knights.

We have these Cases to check :
$A=Kv,B=Kv \tag{1}$
$A=Kv,B=Kt \tag{2}$
$A=Kt,B=Kv \tag{3}$
$A=Kt,B=Kt \tag{4}$
Scenario X :
When we have only (a) , then A is saying that when A=Knave , we have B=Knight. When indeed $A$ is knave  , with $B=Knight$ , it will be true though Knaves have to lie. Hence the Case (2) will not occur. All other Cases can occur , either due to Knave $A$ lying about $B$ or due to Knight $A$ telling the truth.
That is all that we can conclude : Case (2) can not occur.
Scenario Y :
When we only have (b) , then $B$ is claiming that $2+3=5$ , which is true , thus the whole is true. thus $B$ is a Knight.
We can then conclude that while Case (2) might occur , we might have Case (4) too.
Scenario Z :
When we have (a) along with (b) , we know that Case (2) gets eliminated , hence Case (4) will remain.
We can then conclude that we have Case (4) : A=Knight ,B=Knight.

I may be wrong, but I conclude that hey're both Knights. I'm going to post it as an answer.

That is my Conclusion too , @MariuszPopieluch , though there was a "Single-Word" typo  which I rectified now. I was saying Case (4) , which is indeed Correct.
